# How to store list of objects in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to store list of objects in objectlist(Like generic list/ collection in c#) using objective c. How do I accomplish this task.

and I need to access this object list. IF you can provide sample code for this. that is useful...

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: NSMutableArray is best way to store objects.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with this collection? Different types of collections are better at different tasks. For something like an array, you can use [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

An NSMutableArray can be changed later on down the line. I prefer to use these when programming.